# BitmapFactory image decoding in Android, how it is different from iOS?

Tags: base64, inputstream, bitmapfactory, skia

The image is given as Base64 encoded string, I had decode and pass to BitmapFactory class, then I got a log saying **skia returned false**. I did the fix by using **FilterInputStream** still its failing. So to identify the issue with image decoding part, I did the **hexdump** and compare with iOS one, it was identical. So now I'm sure that issue with BitmapFactory class. One thing I noticed that, when I put the binary output to a file and copy to Mac, clicking on the file I could see the image. So I was trying to figure out, what is the different between the Image Decoder in Android and iOS.